# Windows 8.1 | Code d'erreur : 0x80073712

Tags: powershell, windows-8.1

When I try to enable IIS, Windows PowerShell 2.0 (this what I really need because SQL server needs it), I get the following error:

> Code d'erreur : 0x80073712

I tried all solutions that I found on the Internet like:

> http://windows.microsoft.com/fr-xf/windows-8/windows-update-error-0x80073712

but no luck. Help please.

Comment: I severely doubt that doing a Refresh wouldn't work. That's basically the same as reïnstalling Windows.

Comment: Formate PC should do the job i guess , no ?

Comment: not working , guess there is no hope :(

Comment: Did you try a `sfc /scannow`?  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931712